How to Set a Checkbox to Default Checked to Collapse a Menu Bar Initially Using HTML and CSS?
I want a checkbox to be checked by default when the page loads, so that a menu bar is initially collapsed (hidden). How can I achieve this using HTML and CSS?
Here is my current HTML and CSS code:


header #toggler:checked ~ .navbar{
    clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

header .navbar a{
    display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>The CheeseCake Shop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

            <header>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="toggler">
                <label for="toggler" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                    <a href="#products">Products</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </header>

    </body>

</html>




<input type="checkbox" name="" id="toggler" checked>?

Add checked=checked to your checkbox html element.
The page should then load with it checked.
